# How to prevent the user to switch the fragment if data is edited?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a profile settings fragment. When the user edits anything without saving and trying to switch to another fragment it should prevent it and show a dialog. I used to do that on activity by overriding `onBackPressed` method. In a fragment, I've used `onDetach` but it crashes when I put the `super` in the if statement.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {

    if (isProfileChanged) {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDetach()` is lifecycle method its Called when the fragment is no longer attached to its activity. So i.e its meant to get called once you replace or remove the current fragment .

Apart from it you want to restrict user from changing fragment. You should validate the fields and make a decision weather to change fragment or not.
Do this in Activity's `onBackPressed()`. below is an example illustrating the same for reference .

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment =getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerFrame);
    if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof YourFragment) {
        if(((YourFragment) fragment).validate()){
         finish();
       }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Create a `public` method in fragment and validate the field and return `true/false`. Make the use of same method to transaction further .